# How can I select/set which image to use for a Visual Studio App Center project?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-app-center

I am working with an iOS mobile app written in Xamarin forms and distributed ad-hoc through Visual Studio App Center. My problem is that when an end user receives an email with the installation link, the app icon is extremely pixelated. The image used in the email is the 40x40 pixel version intended for notifications/iPad spotlight. I have tried to replace all the images in the project with new versions and made sure that all required icons were provided. However, it always uses the same image in the email.

How can I change the image that App Center uses as the project image?

Comment: I have. All of the images within the Assets.xcassets file have been set and I have a full size version for the App Store icon. Unfortunately, Visual Studio App Center is still using the lowest quality image. I tried updating the image in the main branch, as well as the branch that was being distributed, and neither made a difference.

Comment: Did you set the Source with  `AppIcons` in `Info.plist`?  If you did and problem still exsits,  try to set source `None` , and then try [this](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/working_with_resources/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to posting this question here, I had reached out to the App Center technical team. I heard back from them with the following response:

> For Android we will use the launcher icon size xxhdpi.  For iOS, it is
>   using the CFBundleIcons.CFBundlePrimaryIcon or CFBundleIconFile.  If
>   these are missing, we will use Icon@2x.png or Icon.png from your app
>   directory.   The image update only happens when you release a new
>   binary.  Once you distribute the binary to a a distribution group we
>   will retrieve the new image from your release and use that as the new
>   app image.